# where is the request from light client sent to in blockchain network?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I understand how a stand alone node work in blockchain.

But how does light client fit in the blockchain?

For example: I have a wallet for bitcoin, i send a request to send money to another wallet, where is the request sent to?

Is the request sent to some "middle man" full nodes to verify this transaction or what?

Answer (score 1):

The request is sent from the light client to full nodes and propagated among the full nodes, using peer-to-peer communication over the Internet.

Some of those nodes assemble sets of transactions into draft blocks and attempt to find a nonce that makes the draft block valid.  When one succeeds, it announces this completed block to the network.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it can send the request to any other full nodes? If so, the functionality of light node is basically same as full node than? I mean it can just broadcast it's request to block chain just like a full node? No?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2-4. A light client delivers a subset of the functionality of a full node. Being able to issue a transaction is typically part of the subset.